# ER_PARSE_ERROR JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have the following script:

```
radioStation.on('metadata', function(metadata) {
    var values = (metadata.StreamTitle).split('-').map(i=>i.trim());
    var artist = values[0];
    var title = values[1];
    console.log('webstream');
    console.log(artist); 
    console.log(title);  


    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "",
      database: "radio"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");


      var sql = "INSERT INTO webstream (artist, title) VALUES ( " + artist + " ," + title + ")";
      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
      });
    });
});
```

When i execute the script i will get a ER_PARSE_ERROR.

Does any one know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steve was on the right track. Maybe this will help:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO webstream (artist, title) VALUES ( '" + artist + "', '" + title + "')";
```